# Update Status in ListView in C#

Tags: c#, loops

I have a method that loops through all ListViewItems and for each one I am trying to simulate a delay with this code:

```
lvFiles.Items[i].SubItems.Add("In-Progress");
do 
{
    //loop
} while(DateTime.Now <= stopTime);
lvFiles.Items[i].SubItems[7].Text = "Complete";
```

The problem is that the form "freezes" for x seconds as expected but the status doesn't seem to update visually until all items get looped through...  then all items get marked as "complete" all at once.

What is the problem, and how can I fix this?

Comment: Are you able to post a bit more info. e.g. How you are setting the original items collection + the loop you are using. As a side note, I would recommend just using Thread.Sleep() for delays.

Comment: With such a hight rate of UI updating requirement, no UI can be **rendered**, use a `Timer` instead.

Comment: form freezes : solution is Timer and/or thread you might got a cross thread error to fix it use invoke required properties and invoke function of lvFiles

Comment: @MindingData I adding the items through ListView.Items.AddRange().  I am using a simple Do While() loop as shown in orig post.  I had already tried Thread.Sleep() it produced the same result of the UI not updating in between loops

Comment: @saeed By freezing I mean it is "busy" until all the do loops finish - I haven't tried King Kong suggestion of a Timer yet

Comment: @KingKing I will have to google Timer I have not used it before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a BackgroundWorker similar to this solution substituting with updating the listview instead of a progress bar:

```
private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

    for (int i = 1; (i <= 10); i++)
    {
        if ((worker.CancellationPending == true))
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            // Perform a time consuming operation and report progress.
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            worker.ReportProgress((i * 10), "some data to pass to other thread");
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
private void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //listview update code here - e.Argument cast and parsed to update listview
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Withim your loop try using:

```
Application.DoEvents();
```

Edit:
As per @sa_ddam213 correct comment, it is not good to invoke it in every iteration, so you could build a counter so that it is invoked every x iterations of the loop and not with every iteration.

Comment: @sa_ddam213, I appreciate the 'gentle' hint.

Comment: In general, if you're using `Application.DoEvents()`, you're doing something *horribly wrong*. In this case, a better solution would be to use the `async/await` pattern or use a `BackgroundWorker` to keep the UI thread from blocking.

Comment: @DanielMann, your approach sounds interesting, I should get to learn how to do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is update the UI throughout the process then this would work:

```
lvFiles.BeginInvoke(() => lvFiles.Items[i].SubItems[7].Text = "Complete");
```